# Error expected expression before '{' token

Tags: c

```
typedef struct{
 int num, den;
} tfrac;

tfrac multf(tfrac a, tfrac b);

tfrac multf(tfrac a, tfrac b){
  tfrac res;
  res={a.num*b.num, a.den*b.den}; //The ERROR is here
  return res;
}
```

This program multiplies fractions. I don't know why I have an error in the function.

Comment: What is `res={a.num*b.num, a.den*b.den};` supposed to do?  It's certainly not valid C.

Comment: what datatype is `res` ?

Comment: @brokenfoot: `tfrac`.

Comment: Is there some documentation or example code you saw that lead you to believe that line would work?

Comment: What/who lead you to belive that _typedefing_ a struct would be a good idea?, not a rhetorical question, I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: In the excercise they obligated me to use that struct.

Comment: How can I solve this? :(

Comment: @JennyT-Type typedef'ing structs is very common and idiomatic in C. Why are you asking that question?

Comment: @Barmar Why?, curiosity?. I don't want to assume, I would do that (_typedefing_)to avoid declaring something like `struct mydata_type mysdata_var;` and go for `mydata_type mydata_var` saving me from typing the word `struct` again and some (tiny) disk space along the way, But then I would get into trouble if I forget I'm passing a struct instead of a union or an malloc'ed chunk, so if I would typedef I would have something like `typedef struct s_mydata_type {/* members */} s_mydata_type_t;` then, `typedef union u_myotherdata_type {/* mxmembers */} u_myotherdata_type_t` as reminders (cont).

Comment: (cont'd), but then, some programmers would chastise me about using prefixes (and suffixes) reserved for some future use by the C standard, So i found that refraining from typedefing saves me from using my data in an incorrect way (eg, assigning to members of an union as they were struct members -- not exactly trivial to pinpoint if compiled correctly), and from future concerns. With that being said, I sometimes typedef my structs and/or unions, if, for example, I'm going to use several variables of that type, or complex data structures from an specific type.

Answer (score 0):

An [initializer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)) is a part of a declarator. So you can't declare your variable on one line and then assign values to it with an initializer on another line. Instead:

```
tfrac res={a.num*b.num, a.den*b.den};
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using is not valid in C. You can get pretty close to this syntax in context of *assignment operator* by using a *compound literal*

```
tfrac multf(tfrac a, tfrac b)
{
  tfrac res;
  res = (tfrac) { a.num * b.num, a.den * b.den };
  return res;
}
```

Note the `(tfrac)` part before the `{}`.

But in your case you can simply use initialization instead of assignment

```
tfrac multf(tfrac a, tfrac b)
{
  tfrac res = { a.num * b.num, a.den * b.den };
  return res;
}
```

However, returning to compound literals again, if you prefer, you can use a compound literal to turn the whole thing into an one-liner

```
tfrac multf(tfrac a, tfrac b)
{
  return (tfrac) { a.num * b.num, a.den * b.den };
}
```